# orbeon 2017.2 formbuilder: how to choose checkboxes

Tags: orbeon, formbuilder

In orbeon 2017.2, the bar  with the "summary", "New", ..."Save" buttons hides two selection Controls in the formbuilder menu ( Radio Buttons with "Other" and Checkboxes, see the two screenshots).
What I have to do to choose for example "Checkboxes"?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Note that for Form Builder, [IE isn't supported anymore](http://blog.orbeon.com/2017/12/orbeon-forms-20172.html), and if this is what you're using we recommend you upgrade to Edge 16 (or another browser such as Firefox or Chrome).

Comment: @avernet  I'm using Firefox ESR 52.1.2 (32-bit)    
Now I saw in [Orbeon Forms 2017.2](http://blog.orbeon.com/2017/12/orbeon-forms-20172.html)
 Browser support

    Form Builder (creating forms)
        Chrome 63 (latest stable version)
        Firefox 57 (latest stable version) and the current Firefox ESR
        Microsoft Edge 16 (latest stable release)
        Safari 11 (latest stable version)

So I will install a newer firefox and retry

Comment: @avernet   I tried with Firefox Quantum  portable  57.0.3 (64-bit), but without luck. Two buttons of the toolbox are hidden.

Comment: Got it; this is a regression in 2017.1; sorry about that! For now, I've created [issue #3438](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3438) for this, and we'll include a fix for this in 2017.1.1. In the meantime, as a workaround, would you be able to use Chrome instead of Firefox?

Comment: @avernet   I tried now with chrome portable Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (32-bit)  and all is OK :)

Comment: Excellent, and thanks for the update. On our side, we'll fix this asap, as we definitely want to support Firefox.